# Limit total p:fileUpload temporary files size

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using `<p:fileUpload>` component in "native" mode to upload files to my site. `<p:fileUpload>`allows to limit number of files and each file's size, but I can't find a way to limit total files size for all pages.

Here is the situation that bothers me. Attacker can initiate many very slow uploads from multiple instances of the same page. This way he can use as much space as he wants, even if the limits are set to one 1MiB file. This can possibly interfere with other services.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

First solution is captcha, just require captcha validation before you start upload. Primefaces has ready for use component: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/captcha.xhtml

Second solution is performing validation in a backing bean. Considering that you have @SessionScope bean, where you can define parameter and write inside it total size of uploaded data. Every time when your user upload something your write inside it and check if a user exceeded permitted date before every upload.

Comment: Captcha is a good idea, but attack is still possible, as long as attacker can afford solving enough of them (and there are services that can do it for relatively low price).

Using a backing bean seems like a solution, but i can't find a way to detect the fact, that upload was started, only that it was finished.

Comment: To be more precise - there is a `onstart` callback, but it's on the client side, so can be easily modified.